Need Help Troubleshooting Unexpected Dark Background on SheetContent Component
I’m having an issue with a SheetContent component from Shadcn UI. According to the documentation and the default styling, the SheetContent should have a white background. However, in my project, the background appears dark instead.
It looks like something make it dark.
I would appreciate if you can help me, thanks!
the component:
import { Menu } from "lucide-react";
import { Sheet, SheetContent, SheetDescription, SheetTitle, SheetTrigger } from "./ui/sheet";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { Separator } from "./ui/separator";

type MobileNavProps =
{

};

const MobileNav = ({ }: MobileNavProps) =>
{
  return (
    <Sheet>
        <SheetTrigger>
            <Menu className="text-orange-500" />
        </SheetTrigger>
        <SheetContent>
            <SheetTitle>
                <span>Welcome to MernEats.com!</span>
            </SheetTitle>
            <Separator/>
            <SheetDescription className="flex">
                <Button className="flex-1 font-bold bg-orange-500">Log in</Button>
            </SheetDescription>
        </SheetContent>
    </Sheet>
  );
};

export default MobileNav;

tailwind css config:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    darkMode: ["class"],
    content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
        container: {
            padding: {
              md: "2rem",
            },
          },
        borderRadius: {
            lg: 'var(--radius)',
            md: 'calc(var(--radius) - 2px)',
            sm: 'calc(var(--radius) - 4px)'
        },
        colors: {
            background: 'hsl(var(--background))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--foreground))',
            card: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--card))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--card-foreground))'
            },
            popover: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--popover))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--popover-foreground))'
            },
            primary: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--primary))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--primary-foreground))'
            },
            secondary: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--secondary))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))'
            },
            muted: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--muted))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--muted-foreground))'
            },
            accent: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--accent))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--accent-foreground))'
            },
            destructive: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--destructive))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))'
            },
            border: 'hsl(var(--border))',
            input: 'hsl(var(--input))',
            ring: 'hsl(var(--ring))',
            chart: {
                '1': 'hsl(var(--chart-1))',
                '2': 'hsl(var(--chart-2))',
                '3': 'hsl(var(--chart-3))',
                '4': 'hsl(var(--chart-4))',
                '5': 'hsl(var(--chart-5))'
            }
        }
    }
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}



I’ve tried a few things but can’t seem to get to the bottom of it.
when i set the background of the sheet content to white it works.
i tried to copy a code from shadcn ui of the sheet component which in their website is white and it was dark on my machine.

hey, i am seeing the same issue here! even in light mode, my part of my sheet background is kind dark gray. i havent touch any css yet, have you found the root cause?
